# Restler - Call method from another API class

Tags: restler

In my Restler index.php let's say I've done this:

```php
$r->addAPIClass('Person');
$r->addAPIClass('Team');
```

And now I'm inside one of the methods defined in Person, and I have a need to call one of the methods defined in Team.  What's the right way to get a handle to the Team API so that I can call one of its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special, doing it with Restler.

If it is a static method directly call `Team::method(parameter)`

Otherwise create an instance either

- at constructor if you need it in many methods and store it in a private variable
- at the method level

If you are using a database model, it may already provide you with an instance of team as a relationship

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was some kind of special Scope class